# Can I access the post reach or video views of a media that is posted to aFacebook wall and not a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to fetch the count of post reached and video views of media(image, video or text) that is posted to the Facebook wall of a user.
I am using Facebook Graph API for this purpose.
On doing some research I found that facebook insights are used to fetch the posts reached and video views count. But this data can only be fetched if the media is posted to a page and not to a user's Facebook wall. I have gone through the link below  to confirm this
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights

I even found a link wher we can get the insights of an app using the app_insights feature of Facebook as mentioned in the link:
App Insights /{app-id}/app_insights

Can I fetch the post reached and video view counts of a specific media that is posted to a user's FB account using the app-id/app_insights?
If not, is there any way to access the data for a post made in the Fb wall using Facebook Graph API?

Please suggest!!

Comment: No, insights are not available for user posts. (And you should not need them. If you are doing anything that warrants watching its “performance” in that regard, then it should probably be posted to a page, and not a private user profile in the first place.)

Comment: What does app_insights provide us?

Comment: What the docs describe.

Comment: As @CBroe said, you cannot get insights for user posts. It's clearly mentioned in the Facebook Developers section that insights could only be fetched for Page, Domain and Apps. Follow this link for more info https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'user insights' or equivalent feature in the API

There's [Page Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights) (via the `/insights` edge of a page or page post) or [App Analytics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/app_insights) via the `app_insights` edge on an App